# Wrong swift code, right account number

Tags: bank-account, swift

I have been in a messy situation since last two weeks. The amount in question was for immigration purposes. My sister sent me huge amount from her local UAE bank to my Wise CAD balance ( using CAD global account details ). UAE bank app took the transit code as swift code ( don’t know why ) so money deducted from my sister account with the wrong swift code i.e 062116001. This swift code does not exist at all.

Sender bank claim’s transaction is successful while Wise keep claiming they have not received any amount in their system & I need to contact sender bank.

What will happen with the amount when the swift code is wrong but the account number & name of beneficiary is correct. Is there a chance that it will land in some wrong account ? Whats my best bet to receive the amount back in sender account.